# Posting entity class when only some fields are provided by user

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm curious how people are handling this.

I've used Visual Studio to add CRUD pages with Entity Framework to my Razor Pages application.

But, as is, there's no way the *Create* page is going to validate. That's because the entity has fields such as a user ID, a creation date with default value, and a couple of fields that I want to set default values. So `ModelState.IsValid` is obviously going to return `false`. And it seems like it would rarely be the case that the user will provide exactly the right data for every field of an entity.

One option for dealing with this is to create a new class that has only the fields I need from the user, and then copy them over to the entity before saving it to the database.

The other option is to write code that populates the fields that don't rely on user input before calling `ModelState.IsValid`.

This is a new situation for me. I would love to hear how some other people handle this situation.

Comment: If you are generating the values in your db you can use attribute: 
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]

Comment: @DavidEdel: And what is the purpose of this and how would it help my situation?

Comment: Quote: "fields that I want to set default values." on non-nullable properties that your db assigns valuess (ie date when inserted or generated order number), with above attribute you will be able to add to your db even if the properties are null

Comment: @DavidEdel: Interesting. I will look into this further.

Comment: @DavidEdel: Thanks for this. This looks really handy. Just one note: I would generally want to use `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` for this. This option signifies that the database will generate the value when the record is created. `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` indicates the option is generated both when the record is created and also when it's updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, your first option is more simple and secure if you could use `AutoMapper` instead of copying the values.

Refer to below demo using asp.net core 3.0 Razor Pages:

1.`Install-Package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`

2.Create Model(save to database) and ViewModel(show on user page)

```
public class Movie
{
    public Movie()
    {
        Genre = "Action";        
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }

}

public class MovieViewModel
{

    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

}
```

3.Create AutoMapper `Profile` class

```
public class MovieProfile: Profile    
{
    public MovieProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<MovieViewModel, Movie>().ReverseMap();
    }

}
```

4.Create.cshtml.cs

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public CreateModel(ApplicationContext  context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public MovieViewModel MovieVM { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        Movie movie = _mapper.Map<Movie>(MovieVM);
        _context.Movie.Add(movie);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

Create.cshtml

```
@page
@model RazorpagesCore.Pages.Movies.CreateModel
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MovieVM.Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MovieVM.Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MovieVM.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MovieVM.ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MovieVM.ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MovieVM.ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have personally always handled this situation by having a separate class used in the front-end that will abstract the EF class. This provides benefits such as:

1. Allowing only some fields to be filled by the user prior to saving (such as your case) but not others such as the ID, Timestamps, etc.
2. Reduction of coupling - Allowing for easier refactor of either the front-end or back-end code without the need to also refactor the other (given that the front-end class does not change).
3. [Edit] This prevents any user edit for fields like ID which are not intended to be updated by users.

A downside of this is that it can result in many mappings between similar classes, but an automapper tool can alleviate that to a degree.

Answer (score 0):

I use hidden inputs.

```html
<hidden asp-for="UserId" value=@GetUser() />
<hidden asp-for="CreatedDate" value=@DateTime.Now.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy") />
```

They'll get submitted as part of the form along with the rest of the model. It's the simplest solution, imo.

Comment: That's easier, but I see some potential problems with this. The main issue is that a sophisticated user could potentially edit these values. So it's less secure.